# How to secure or ignore SSL certificate validation in the internet-less server?

Tags: linux, ssl, linux-networking

How I can secure or ignore SSL certificate validation in the internet-less CentOS server?

My app server was in a local network and my server only has access to a specific API server for example: `https://api.kavenegar.com/v1/0/utils/getdate.json`, but my server cannot validate that SSL certificate and get an SSL error with the command `curl`, or etc.

note: I can't get internet access for this server!

```
curl -v https://api.kavenegar.com/v1/0/utils/getdate.json
```

Comment: Have you tried --insecure/-k?

Answer (score 3):

Sign the certificate with a CA trusted by your system CA store. Install the CA to your system trusted certs if it is not there already.

Test the CA file outside of your cert store with [`curl --cacert`](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2018/11/07/get-the-ca-cert-for-curl/). Some additional notes are in curl's [sslcerts docs](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html).

(Not having Internet access doesn't really change this, still need to do TLS properly.)